# SQL: Joining tables and dividing each cell by match cell in another table?

Tags: sql, join, match, union, where-clause

Here is my population dataset detailing the population of each state through 2010 - 2019:

[image: Population Data set]

Here is my consumer complaints dataset which has date received and state:

[image: Consumer complaints Data set]

I already have the complaints for each state per year:

[image: State per Year]

I know I need to join compltsbypear and uspop on state and divide 2011(from complaints) / 2011 from uspop, etc for each match year.

How do I write the query that shows the states and for each year, the ratio of complaints to population?

Comment: (1) Tag your question with the database you are using.  (2) Sample data and desired results *as text tables* is preferred.  (3) All code should always be included as text and not as images.  (4) A db/sql fiddle would help.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I would approach this by unpivoting the population data, so there is one row per state and year.  Then aggregate the complaints and `join`.

Your code looks like SQL Server, so I will use those conventions:

```
with up as (
      select v.*
      from uspop u cross apply
           (values (u.area, 2010, u.[2010]),
                   (u.area, 2011, u.[2011]),
                   . . . 
          ) v(state, year, pop)
     ),
     cc as (
      select year(datereceived) as year, state, count(*) as num_complaints
      from consumercomplaints cc
      group by year(datereceived), state
     )
select up.state, up.year, cc.num_complaints, up.pop,
       (cc.num_complaints * 1.0 / up.pop) as complaint_ratio
from up join
     cc
     on up.state = cc.state and up.year = cc.year;
```

This produces the results you want in a perfectly reasonable format of one row per state/year.  If you want it in a different format, you seem to be aware of how to pivot the data.

Comment: Thank you so much! This was super helpful and allowed me to get what I needed. I believe for the `v(area, year, pop)` part, area is supposed to be state. It worked after I made that slight change.